# results of as.character depends on vector contents (re: pasting a POSIX date-time)

Tags: r, datetime

I have a date.

Here is an example (generated by `mydate <- lubridate::now()`):

```
mydate <- structure(1361998255.23362, class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")
```

if I place this in a vector it looks okay:

(based on @joran's comment, I reduced the example that originally used `as.character` to only use `c`. Now I provide both cases)

```
> c(mydate)
[1] "2013-02-27 14:50:55 CST"
> as.character(mydate)
[1] "2013-02-27 14:50:55"
```

however, if I try to combine it with another element that is a character, the date-time formatting is stripped:

```
> c('a', mydate)
[1] "a"                "1361998255.23362"
> as.character('a', mydate)
[1] "a"                "1361998255.23362"
```

in both cases, the output is of class "character"

Why does `c` provide different results depending on the contents of the input vector? is adding `as.character(mydate)` a suitable solution?

```
> c('a', as.character(mydate))
[1] "a"                   "2013-02-27 14:50:55"
```

The only downside to this: if I am entering a vector with five dates, I'd rather not have to write as.character five times.

*context:* the above is a minimal reproducible example. The context is that I am passing a vector into a function that converts a vector to a comma-delimited string, for the purpose of writing sql statements: `function(x) paste(paste("'", x, "'", sep=''), collapse=',')`

Comment: Note that `c()` coerces to character already. You'll get the same thing in your last example without the `as.character`.

Comment: @joran thanks for pointing that out. The issue still remains, but I will change the examples to use `c(mydate)` and `c('a', mydate)` to simplify further.

Comment: Speculation: `c()` first removes attributes, which leaves just the numeric value underlying the date-time and then coerces to character, while the POSIXct S3 method invoked by `as.character` does not.

Comment: My speculation was just confirmed to me in the R chat room. You probably just want to use `as.character` (it is vectorized, if that helps).

Comment: @joran you have gotten me on the right path, but from `?c`: The output type is determined from the highest type of the components in the hierarchy NULL < raw < logical < integer < real < complex < character < list < expression.). Thus, `is.POSIXct(c(mydate)) == TRUE`

Comment: @Abe: keep reading. The very next paragraph says, "`c` is sometimes used for its side effect of removing attributes, except names, ...".  `class` is an attribute and is therefore removed, leaving only the underlying number.

Comment: You need to distinguish between classes, types, and modes. The list of "types" in that sentence is a hierarchy of types and the mode of POSIXct objects is "double". (The type of  factor classed objects is "integer".)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> in both cases, the output is of class "character"

This is not correct

```
> class(c(mydate))
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
> dput(c(mydate))
structure(1361998255.23362, class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))
```

`c(mydate)` is still a `POSIXt` object. When printed, it looks like a character, but it isn't a character. `c` has this behavior with `POSIXt` objects because there is a specialized `c.POSIXct` function.

In the second case, the first argument is a character, so it defaults to the (internal) version of `c`. This does two things: it strips attributes except names and the promotes to the type that can represent all the elements (See the help page for `c`). Stripping the attributes of `mydate` gives

```
> as.vector(mydate)
[1] 1361998255
```

Promoting the number to a character gives

```
> as.character(as.vector(mydate))
[1] "1361998255.23362"
```

This string is now concatenated with `"a"` to give the results you saw.

```
> c('a', mydate)
[1] "a"                "1361998255.23362"
```

---

Regarding multiple `as.character()` calls to get the coercion at the right time, you can wrap all the dates together with `c` (which uses `c.POSIXct`) and the call `as.character` on that

```
> c('a', as.character(c(mydate, mydate)))
[1] "a"                   "2013-02-27 12:50:55" "2013-02-27 12:50:55"
```

Answer (score 4):

The c() function coerces to the "common denominator type". When you concatenate a numeric and character vector you get all character values. Wehn you combine a logical and numeric vector you get all numeric values. If you want these to remain separate modes, then use the `list()` function rahter than the `c()` function. The full hierarchy is listed at"

```
 ?c
```

"The output type is determined from the highest type of the components in the hierarchy NULL < raw < logical < integer < real < complex < character < list < expression." Notice that this really is talking about types since 'integer', 'real' and 'complex' are all of mode "numeric". It' not however a comple listing of all types:

```
?mode
?typeof
```

In your use case why not use this:

```
function(x) paste(paste("'", as.character(x), "'", sep=''), collapse=',')
```

Comment: It's more nuanced than that.  It would work as the OP expects if it were _coerced_ via `as.character`, but it's not.  Attributes are dropped before conversion to character, leaving only the underlying number.

Comment: I don't think it's more nuanced that what I stated, but what you say about ones access to controlling the coercion is correct.

Comment: After thinking about it, now I agree that there were issues above an beyond the converting of types. Sorry for being defensive.

Comment: Thanks for the apology. Your defensiveness almost made me cry... :P